# How to resize an image by rolling in or out with mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a short piece of code for my Art Teacher, willing to do something like displaying *many **images*** inside a **frame**, which will be in my case, the **Apple Logo** (yeah *empty* inside in order to see the pics).

MY question is, if I'd like to start the **frame's size** at (i.e.) `100 px`, and **resize** it til `10px` by rollin' the mouse wheel just like if you need to **scroll down** the page, how may I do that? I'm using `Javascript`, this must be a *webpage* keep it mind.

Just need to know how to **resize** an **image**by **scrolling** down, instead of scrolling **down** the page (Which will be **static**! :)

If you need more infos, just ask don't skip over please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an event listener for the wheel event, prevent the default action (which is to scroll the window), and then based on the delta value increase or decrease the images width/height

[Wheel Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)

```
document.querySelector("#yourImagesId").addEventListener("wheel",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //check e.wheelDelta to determine what to do
});
```

Demo

```js
document.querySelector("#myImg").addEventListener("wheel",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.wheelDelta < 0){
    var newHeight = $("#myImg").height() - 10;
     $("#myImg").height(newHeight);  
  } else if(e.wheelDelta > 0){
    var newHeight = $("#myImg").height() + 10;
     $("#myImg").height(newHeight);  
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height:3000px;  
}

img:hover {
  outline:2px solid #00FF00;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="myImg">
```

Comment: Amazing! And what if I'd like to set a default size which can't be larger or shorter? @PatrickEvans

Comment: Just check the images size before doing the resize, if it is larger or shorter than do not do the resize

Comment: Yeah, great thank you! I'll let you have the link it I'm gonna make it work :P